# Why transition with translate is taking up space even though div has no height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/taylor-austin/pen/zaJgKY?editors=1111) of what I am talking about.

Essentially I want to transition a `div` to move up and down smoothly but have the other `div`'s take its space and transition with it at the same time without having to separately transition them all. I figured they would take up the space since these `div`s have no height. But I was wrong!

If you inspect the empty space it has no dimensions and it is like as if empty air is taking up the space. For some reason the other `div`'s aren't moving up.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1')

function myFunc(e) {
  div1.classList.toggle('animate')
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.div2 {
  background: green;
}

.div3 {
  background: blue;
}

.animate {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunc()">Toggle</button>
<div class="div1">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: translate is only a visual effect, it will not affect the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using margin instead of transform because transform is only a **visual** effect and will not change the layout.

> Note: Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no
>   affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)</sup>

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1')

function myFunc(e) {
  div1.classList.toggle('animate')
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background: red;
  margin-top:-300px;
  transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.div2 {
  background: green;
}

.div3 {
  background: blue;
}

.animate {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunc()">Toggle</button>
<div class="div1">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will help you to get the answer

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.main-div')

function myFunc(e) {
  div1.classList.toggle('animate')
}
```

```css
.main-div {
  transform: translateY(-350%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.div1 {
background: red;
}

.div2 {
  background: green;
}

.div3 {
  background: blue;
}

.animate {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunc()">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div">
<div class="div1">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are animating each div (essentially, by wrapping with one giant div), I stated I do not want to do that.